# The lesser of two evils (Grec ancien : Mḕ kheíron béltiston)

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

[En grec ancien :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases#%CE%9C%CE%BC)

> Mὴ χεῖρον βέλτιστον. Mḕ kheíron béltiston.

Littéralement (en anglais) :

> "The least bad [choice] is the best."
>
> I.e. When there is no good option, one should pick the one that is  the cause of 
>   the least harm.

En anglais on dit :

> The lesser of two evils.

Mot pour mot cette expression devrait être en français :

> Le moindre de deux maux.

Existe-t-il d'autres expressions francisées plus idiomatiques ou imagées ?

Comment: On dit plutôt "le moindre des deux maux" au lieu de "de".

Comment: Toujours du mal avec de et des :-)! Donc, il n'y pas d'autres expressions plus idiomatiques que celle-ci ?

Comment: Ça me semble la plus appropriée.

Comment: Dans le cas général on dit « le moindre **de** deux mots  » : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+moindre+de+deux+maux%2Cle+moindre+des+deux+maux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20moindre%20de%20deux%20maux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20moindre%20des%20deux%20maux%3B%2Cc0
 Le cas particulier (des) n'est pas autant utilisé.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En langage soutenu, on peut utiliser une expression qui a la même construction qu'en anglais : « choisir le moindre de deux maux ». C'est *de*, pas *des*, parce qu'il s'agit de la préposition *de* suivie de l'article partitif au pluriel (*de* + pluriel de *de le/la*), et non pas suivie de l'article défini au pluriel (*de* + pluriel de *le/la*). On parle de deux maux non spécifiés en général.

On peut aussi utiliser le superlatif *moindre* comme un adjectif. Cela donne l'expression « *moindre mal* » qui est assez courante.

> Il n'y a pas de bonne solution, il faut choisir le moindre mal.
>
> Cette solution n'est pas idéale, mais c'est un moindre mal.

Le mot *[moindre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moindre)* est une forme comparative ou superlative de l'adjectif *petit*. Il a un côté littéraire et légèrement vieilli, à part dans l'expression « *un moindre mal* » est en train de devenir un forme figée qui reste fréquemment utilisée même en registre courant. Dans un registre plus courant, on utilise plutôt le groupe adjectival « moins mauvais » que le groupe nominal « moindre mal ».

> Il n'y a pas de bonne solution, il faut choisir la moins mauvaise.

En langage familier, on dit souvent « <sup>?</sup>*moins pire* » pour « *moins mauvais* ». Ce n'est pas grammaticalement correct, puisque *pire* est déjà un comparatif, mais c'est au départ une faute assumée et elle est en train d'entrer dans la langue.

> Y'a pas d'bonne solution, mais on va prend' celle-là, c'est la moins pire.
> (= Il n'y a pas de bonne solution, mais nous allons prendre celle-là, c'est la moins mauvaise.)

Answer (score 3):

Le texte grec correspond probablement à une citation d'Aristote qui est traduite en français par le proverbe connu:

> Entre deux maux, il faut choisir le moindre.

On dit aussi souvent:

> Le moindre mal

Answer (score 3):

L'expression "le moindre des deux maux" est en effet la plus appropriée. Son origine est expliquée ici: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moindre (II A, locution proverbiale: "De deux maux il faut choisir le moindre").

A noter, l'emploi de "de" dans le proverbe est dû à la généralité du proverbe (entre n'importe quel deux maux). "Des" implique que l'on parle de deux maux particuliers.